# Need advice on correcting a floor dip

Tags: flooring, floor, subfloor, joists

I have an older house (1940’s) with a dip in the hallway leading to my downstairs (1st floor) bathroom.  From wall to wall the hallway is 14 feet with the wood floor joists below running parallel to the length.  I ran a line level and found the floor is dipped 2 1/4” max at about 1/3 of the length of the hallway.  This 1/3 length point is closer to the bathroom.
Here’s what I’ve done so far:

- Looked for cracks in the floor joists from the basement.  No cracks were found.
- Pulled tile up in the hallway to find that the previous owner tried minimizing the dip with the addition of plywood where the dip is at its lowest and blended the tile around it in.
- Had a few foundation repair companies come take a look.  They both suggested jack/post systems to prevent any further dipping, but not a solution to level the floor.  One quoted $2600 and the other $5600 for their specialized jack/post system.  Again, the jack/posts they said would be used to support the joists, but wouldn’t do anything about the floor dip. They felt that the dip was caused by the joists getting wet at some point and warping.  These joists are old rough hewn 2x8’s.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Would you post a picture of the basement joists in the affected area?

Comment: Is it just the hallway floor that dips not the area on either side ?

Comment: It is most noticeable in the hallway, but there is a slight dip on the other side of the wall (kitchen and living room).

Comment: I spoke with a carpenter today who said he thinks the joists dipped due to the weight from the second floor addition that was installed many years ago.  He suggested running a beam perpendicular to the joists in the area of the dip, jacking the dip level, and installing 2 lally columns.

Comment: I’ve been trying to upload a photo of the joists, but am apparently technologically challenged on here.  I took some string and ran it from the joist supports on either side of the basement (parallel one of the joists in the affected area).  Although not very accurate due to wiring and joist cross-bracing partially obstructing the string from riding up the joist...there is 1.5” of dip in the bottom of the joist.  I’m thinking that the carpenter’s solution is valid.

Comment: Just wondering if it’s a good idea to make the correction all in one day or gradually throughout a week to minimize cracked drywall.  Also, is removing a 2’x2’ concrete section and pouring a dedicated footer for the lally columns necesary?  The existing slab is at least 2’ thick.